# Cancelling a pthread and printf behaviour

Tags: c, pthreads, printf, cancellation

Here is a code sample of pthread cancellation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *my_routine(void *arg) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  pthread_t thread;
  if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, my_routine, NULL)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create pthread\n");
    return 1;
  }
  usleep(20);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  //fflush(stdout);
  sleep(1);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile with:

```
gcc -pthread -Wall threadtest.c -o threadtest
```

When executing, sometimes, it prints an additional number **after** `sleep(1)`.

Sometimes this number is a duplicate:

```
0
1
2
3
4
4  // printed after sleep(1)
```

Sometimes not:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5  // printed after sleep(1)
```

If I `fflush(stdout)` before `sleep(1)`, then the additional number is printed immediately.

How can I avoid this weird `printf` behaviour when cancelling a thread?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable cancellation while doing the `printf()` and add an explicit cancellation point:

```
int cancel_state = 0;
pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, &cancel_state);
printf("%d\n", i);
pthread_setcancelstate(cancel_state);
pthread_testcancel();
```

(error checking left out for the sake of readability)

Comment: Yes, it "works" (I give `NULL` as second parameter of `pthread_setcancelstate`), but this is not a solution. I cannot believe that, while `printf` is a *cancellation point*, it does not behave correctly when cancelled.

Comment: @rom1v: `printf()` uses a shared resource, that is `stdout`. Most propably the thread leaves something in `stdout`'s output buffer as it can not finish it's work as it is cancelled. This left-over then is printed out by the main thread on `fflush()` or exit. Access to shared resources shall be protected.

Comment: Shall be protected by what? I tried with `flockfile`/`funlockfile` (with `pthread_cleanup_push`/`pthread_cleanup_pop`), without success. And a mutex won't help: this is not a multi-thread access problem, it seems a cancellation problem, that `printf` don't handle correctly (it should not accept cancellation in the middle of its work).

Comment: @rom1v: In this case "protected" against incomplete usage. "*... it should not accept cancellation in the middle of its work. ...*" That's what my approach is taking care of.

Comment: @alk the question is whether printf is allowed to to be cancelled in the middle of doing work. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html isn't entierly clear. One one hand it says printf may be a cancellation point (and if so, that means it should not leave stuff in a broken state) - and it also says other (posix)functions should not be a cancellation point. Which in my interpretation means printf either is a cancellation point and leaves stuff consistently, or is not a cancellation point and doesn't react at all to a cancel request

Comment: @nos: Thanks for linking the standard, where I found another interesting paragraph: "*The side effects of acting upon a cancellation request while suspended during a call of a function are the same as the side effects that may be seen in a single-threaded program when a call to a function is interrupted by a signal and the given function returns [EINTR].*" Could we draw from this that any not async-signal-save function isn't thread-cancellation-safe?

Comment: However, referreing to the OP's test case: I'd feel printing the `5` is Ok, printing the `4` **twice** I'd consider a bug in how `printf()`handles cancellation.

Comment: @alk I don't think you can make that connection. The standard lists a set of function that are cancellation points, a set of functions that might be cancellation points, and forbids other functions in the standard to be cancellation points. And I don't think yielding EINTR is allowed to leave stuff in an inconsistent state either. So e.g. printf is either a cancellation point, and if so it must behave predictably, or it's not a cancellation point so it completes as normal even if a cancellation request is pending.

Answer (score 1):

When using pthread_cancel you should take more care on thread handler.

man page of pthread_cancel explain lot about this.

> man pthread_cancel

Check the example program available in the man page

When thread handler start you have to make PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE with the help of pthread_setcancelstate system call, when handler meet the cancellation point set PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE.

In the main check the pthread_cancel success or not with the help of PTHREAD_CANCELED macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *my_routine(void *arg) {
  int i;
  //pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sleep(1);
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
  //pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
  sleep(60);
  return NULL;
}
int main(void) 
{
  pthread_t thread;
  if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, my_routine, NULL)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create pthread\n");
    return 1;
  }
usleep(20);
pthread_cancel(thread);
pthread_join(thread, NULL);
//fflush(stdout);
sleep(1);
return 0;
}
```

1. Initially compile and run the above program, note the output. It may not display anything and terminate the program because after thread created thread handler will wait 1sec and sleep, in that time parent thread will cancel the thread and finish process.
2. Then uncomment the two pthread_setcancelstate() from above program, now compile and run the program. It will now display from 1 to 9. Because thread is set as PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE so parent pthread_cancel will not cancel and wait for PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE.When thread handler meet PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE parent thread will cancel the thread.
3. when you note the output. handler will not stay on sleep(60), because before that parent will cancel the thread.

Comment: OK, but my point is that `printf` **is** a *cancellation point*, but that we should never rely on it. I thought it would be logical that, with a thread having a cancel type `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED`, the cancellation point in `printf` would avoid to let garbage in stdout…